# Dependent: :destroy only to the 2nd degree in has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have three models. A `collection` has many `searches` through `items`.
When a `collection` is destroyed, I'd like its `items` to be destroyed, but `searches` to be nullified, since they are still valid objects on their own.
Can this be done?

Here are my models:

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :searches, through: :items
  has_many :items
  has_many :searches, through: :suggestions
  has_many :suggestions
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :search
end

class Search < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :collections, through: :items
  has_many :items
  has_many :collections, through: :suggestions
  has_many :suggestions
end
```

Comment: you could write a method to do this. Would be explicit

Comment: Thanks! I was sure there would be a way to call `dependent: destroy` on `has_many :items` and `dependent :nullify` on `has_many :searches, through :items`, but I guess there is none?

Comment: btw, you need to rename one of `has_many :searches`. Model can't have two different associations with the same names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* just delete the items, just add `dependent: :destroy` to `has_many :items`.

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :searches, through: :items
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

After destroying a collection, the item is destroyed but the search will remain.

**second solution**

You could even apply `dependent: :nullify` to `has_many :searches` - getting the same result.

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :searches, through: :items, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :items
end
```

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> **collection.delete(object, …)**
>
> Removes one or more objects from the collection by setting their foreign keys to `NULL`. Objects will be in addition destroyed if they're associated with `dependent: :destroy`, and deleted if they're associated with `dependent: :delete_all`.
>
> If the `:through` option is used, then the join records are deleted (rather than nullified) by default, but you can specify `dependent: :destroy` or `dependent: :nullify` to override this.